# How to find the coordinates value of all the points which divides the line into 5 equal parts

Tags: javascript, java, math

How to divide a line into n equal parts, eg- 5 equal parts.

For example I need to add 5 points on a straight line based on starting and ending point XY co-ordinates given below:
Starting point :

```
X1 : 0.27176220806794055
Y2 : 0.7258064516129032
```

Ending Point

```
X1 : 0.6303191489361702
Y2 : 0.348993288590604
```

How to find the coordinates value of all the points which divides the line into 5 equal parts.

Comment: well, what have you tried so far? (start with: [y = m*x + b](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/linear-equations.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the distance between the start and end points by 5 for each component separately, and use this to compute all the interior points:

```js
function divideIntoFiveSegments(startPoint, endPoint) {
    let {x: x1, y: y1} = startPoint;
    let {x: x2, y: y2} = endPoint;

    let dx = (x2 - x1) / 5; 
    let dy = (y2 - y1) / 5;

    let interiorPoints = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        interiorPoints.push({x: x1 + i*dx, y: y1 + i*dy});

    return [startPoint, ...interiorPoints, endPoint];
}
```

This returns an array of 6 points (2 end points + 4 interior points), which defines a line with 5 segments.

You can call the function like this:

```
divideIntoFiveSegments({x: 0.27176220806794055, y: 0.7258064516129032}, {x: 0.6303191489361702, y: 0.348993288590604});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below link for the formula to divide a line in a certain ratio:

http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Analytical%20Geometry/AnalGeom_3.htm

Now in your case the ratios will be 1:5, 2:5, 3:5 and 4:5. Apply the formula and get your points.

Now to code this in JAVA/javascript you need to create a function which will take both cordinates and the ratio. This function will then return the required points. Then you can call this function for all the different ratios to get the points.